# How to call method from one component to other component angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8

I have created two components named as TableComponent and DetailComponent.
These two are separate component.

TableComponent contain below function

```
detailByID() {
    alert("test);

}
```

i have button in **DetailComponent**, i want to call detailByID function of TableComponent on button click of DetailComponent

```
<button id="detail" (click)="detailByID()"></button>
```

Please suggest how to do this..

Comment: There many ways of achieving it. Check the Input-Output in Angular or RxJS. Consider using a service in between them for the state management

Answer (score 1):

I would say it's situation based question, meaning it depends on how both components are related to each other, example:

1. If your TableComponent is parent component of DetailComponent:

***Solution:*** You can go with **Event-emitter**. Please emit an event from DetailComponent that can call TableComponent function. [EventEmitter](https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-output-and-eventemitter-in-angular)

2. If your DetailComponent is parent component of TableComponent:

**Solution**: You can go with **TempRef Variable**, which will help you to call child component methods in the parent component template. [TempRef](http://www.writesomecode.in/Angular/Using-Template-Reference-Variables-In-Angular7)

3. If there is no connection between both components:

***Solution***: You can go with **Rxjs** **Observables**. [RxjsObservables](https://angular.io/guide/observables-in-angular)

*Please select any way depends on how it's fit for your use-case.*

Answer (score 0):

**table component template**

```
<app-detail (update)="detailByID()"></app-detail>
```

**detail component template**

```
<button id="detail" (click)="update.emit()"></button>
```

**detail component**

```
@Output()
update = new EventEmiter();
```